# I need to fit a best circle to the 3D data in matlab

Tags: matlab

Basically, I have a many irregular circle on the ground in the form of x,y,z coordinates (of 200*3 matrix).  but I want to fix a best circle in to the data of x,y,z coordinates (of 200*3 matrix).

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would try using the [RANSAC algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RANSAC) which finds the parameters of your model (in your case a circle) given noisy data. The algorithm is quite easy to understand and robust against outliers.

The wikipedia article has a Matlab example for fitting a line but it shouldn't be too hard to adapt it to fit a circle.

[These](http://www.asl.ethz.ch/education/master/info-process-rob/Hough-Ransac.pdf) slides give a good introduction to the RANSAC algorithm (starting from page 42). They even show examples for fitting a circle.

Answer (score 0):

Though this answer is late, I hope this helps others

To fit a circle to 3d points

1. Find the centroid of the 3d points (nx3 matrix)
2. Subtract the centroid from the 3D points.
3. Using RANSAC, fit a plane to the 3D points. You can refer [here](https://www.peterkovesi.com/matlabfns/) for the function to fit plane using RANSAC
4. Apply SVD to the 3d points (nx3 matrix) and get the v matrix
5. Generate the axes along the RANSAC plane using the axes from SVD. For example, if the plane norm is along the z-direction, then cross product between the 1st column of v matrix and the plane norm will generate the vector along the y-direction, then the cross product between the generated y-vector and plane norm will generate a vector along the x-direction. Using the generated vectors, form a Rotation matrix [x_vector y_vector z_vector]
6. Multiply the Rotation matrix with the centroid subtracted 3d points so that the points will be parallel to the XY plane.
7. Project the points to XY plane by simply removing the Z-axes from the 3d points
8. fit a circle using [Least squares circle fit](https://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22678-circle-fit-taubin-method?s_tid=FX_rc1_behav)
9. Rotate the center of the circle using the inverse of the rotation matrix obtained from step 5
10. Translate back the center to the original location using the centroid

The circle in 3D will have the center, the radius will be the same as the 2D circle we obtained from step 8, the circle plane will be the RANSAC plane we obtained from step 3