# Best fit circle for 3D data, [Matlab]

Tags: matlab

I have my 3D data X,Y,Z (Matrices with size `X = 200*1`, `Y = 200*1`, `Z = 200*1`)

I want to fit the data to the best fit circle

Comment: Please post an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: There is no easy answer to your question. Entire books have been written about the subject. A good point to start is [Nikolai Chernov's book](http://people.cas.uab.edu/~mosya/cl/).

Comment: Please edit your initial question if you have detail to add instead of asking the same one another time.

Comment: you can refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51834675/5725763)

Answer (score 0):

You have 200 pts in 3d space. And a circle also in 3d space, the circle is defined by its centre (3variables), orientation (normal to the circus, so 2 more variables, since its length does not matter) and radius (one more variable), Given a circle and an abitrary point, the distance from the pt to the circle is given by one side of a triangle formed by taking a line from the point to the centre of the triangle then to the radius. This will be defined in terms of the 7 variables (centre, orientation, radius), now you have two hundred distances, sum them and this is a formula in terms of radius, orientation and position, now put this formula inside any of the matlab optimizers and you will find the optimal centre,orientation, radius. This is for sure a convex problem...

Comment: your answer is not clear, can you please explain with some algorithm or code 

thanks in Advance